# Using imageData for texture in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping

I try to load a imageData to create texture in threeJS. 
I try like this, but it does not work.

```
pMaterial =
new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xFFFFFF,
    size: 20,
    map: THREE.DataTexture(
        myimageData
        ),
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    transparent: true
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please define what "doesn't work" means...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works with the following code.

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture(myImageData);
texture.needsUpdate = true;

particles = new THREE.Geometry(),
pMaterial =
new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
    size: 20,
    map: texture,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    transparent: true
});
```

Comment: The important part is `texture.needsUpdate = true;`. Without it, the texture would be just black.